# Swift/ Xcode 7 issue with CocoaPods installing SlackTextViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I did all these stpes one by one it worked before but now it does not works.
heres the steps: 
1- Cd project/   << the the project folder 
2-pod init
3-open -a Xcode Podfile
4-xcode open > delete the text replace it with 
5- pod install

in the project folder I got **PodFile** + **file named :Pods**

```
    Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.39.0.rc.1 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../../../../../../../SharedFrameworks in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../..//DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTInstrumentsFoundation being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/Xcode3Core being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
Downloading dependencies
Installing SlackTextViewController (1.7)
Generating Pods project
2015-10-06 17:40:44.328 ruby[24848:729221] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-8228/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:590
Details:  Assertion failed: _initializationCompletedSuccessfully
Function: BOOL IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction()
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fda9385d7c0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010a433a4c -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010a4331d9 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010a433445 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010a4333a7 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010d24cf5c IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x000000010fd28e49 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x000000010fd2a9ce +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x00007fff96db4f14 ffi_call_unix64 (in libffi.dylib)
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to install in an example project with no issues following the steps:

1. cd project
2. sudo gem install cocoapods (type your password)
3. pod setup
4. pico Podfile (it creates a Podfile) 
   In my Podifle:

   platform : ios, '8.0'

   pod 'SlackTextViewController'
5. pod install